# MudBlazor: How can I align a MudIcon so that it aligns with a MudText?

Tags: css, mudblazor

In MudBlazor what is the cleanest way to align a MudIcon with some corresponding MudText.

```
{
  <CardHeaderContent>
     <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Align="Align.Center">
       <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Business" Title="Favorite" /> Company Details
      </MudText>
  </CardHeaderContent>
}
```

The above icon doens't align with the text.

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have the `MudIcon` as a child content of `MudText`, then you can turn the `MudText` into a flexbox and `align-center`.

```
<CardHeaderContent>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
        <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Business" Title="Favorite" /> Company Details
    </MudText>
</CardHeaderContent>
```

Comment: thou a cleaner method it didn't actually align the text with the icon for me.

Comment: @Choco Hmm what code were you using when it didn't work? Because based off the code in your question it is working as intended.  [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mumHYBGpTclkCjgE)

Comment: Don't know! but played with your snippet and it worked very well. Maybe I have some css side effects going on. I've accepted your answer. thx

Comment: @choco alright, as long as it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I figgured this out:

```
      <CardHeaderContent>
        <div class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
          <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Business" Title="Favorite" />
          <MudText Typo="Typo.h6"> Company Details</MudText>
        </div>
      </CardHeaderContent>
```

I wrapped the content in a div and added d-flex & align-centre. the justify-centre is just to center the text in the container and not needed to align the icon with the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use the **MudStack** component:

```
<MudStack Row=true>
    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PersonPinCircle"/>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.H6">Stuff</MudText>
</MudStack>
```

The row attribute forces a horizontal stacking of the child elements.

Also, I notice that your text in the MudText element has a leading space. I would recommend you remove this, and instead use the Class attribute of the MudText element to take care of that. Something as simple as:

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.H6" Class="ml-3">Company Name</MudText>
```

Or ml-2 or whatever, but it will handle the spacing a little better, I think.